# Dynamic Content Parsing

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, jsoup, web-crawler

I am working with content parsing I executed the sample program for this i have taken a sample link
please visit the below link

http://www.equitymaster.com/stockquotes/sector.asp?sector=0%2CSOFTL&utm_source=top-menu&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=performance&utm_content=key-sector

or

[Click Here](http://www.equitymaster.com/stockquotes/sector.asp?sector=0,SOFTL&utm_source=top-menu&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=performance&utm_content=key-sector)

in the above link i parsed the table data and store into java object.

BSE and NSE are not my exact requirement just I am taken sample example. the above link is developed in the tables they are not used id's and classes. in my example I parsed data using XPath

this is my Xpath

```
/html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/font/table[2]
```

I selected and parsing it is working fine . here is a problem in future if they **changed website structure** my program will not work for sure. tell me any other way to parse data dynamically and able to store in database. display the results based on the condition even if they **changed the webpage structure** I used for this JSOUP api for this. Tell me any other ApI's which provide best support for this type of requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to parse a page without any clear id/class to select your nodes, you have to try and rely on something else. Redefining the whole tree is indeed the weakest way of doing it, if anything is added/changed everything will collapse.

You could try relying on color: `//table[@bgcolor="#c9d0e0"]`, the "GET MORE INFO" field: `//table[tr/td//text()="GET MORE INFO"]`, the "More Info" there is on every line: `//table[.//td//text()="&nbspMore Info&nbsp"]`...

The idea is to find something ideally unique (if you can't find any unique criteria, `table[color condition selecting a few tables][2]` is still stronger walking the whole tree), present every time, and use that as an id.

Comment: selecting with color it is working fine table[bgcolor=#c9d0e0].for better thing i tried the following Elements elem = doc.select("table:contains(SCRIPT)"); it displaying parent table also.how to select specific table

Comment: Really not sure what you mean... What is this "SCRIPT"? If this selects the parent node you can do `node//table` to see all tables enclosed but I believe you already know that

Comment: i mean to select with scriptor bse or nse